# when opening my site opens a popup with two options accept cookies or if cookies are disabled then not use our site without allow cookies

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

hi I want to add a method in my site js or html, when opening my site opens a popup with two options accept cookies or if cookies are disabled then not use our site without allow cookies.

Answer (score 0):

you can set up web server to answer only when browser has sent "has accept cookie" Otherwise just show popup page. So user can see site only if accept cookie and it has enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create your own popup, you can start by learning how to create modals in JS (example: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp) as well as Cookies in JS (example https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp).

But, if you want avoid "reinventing the wheel",  there's a few turn-key solutions I found online:

Cookie Bar: https://cookie-bar.eu/

GDPR Cookie Consent Prompt: https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/GDPR-Cookie-Consent-Popup-Plugin.html